# at least one class field is not null

Tags: c#

I've a class:

```
public class A
{
   public string field1 {get;set;}
   public string field2 {get;set;}
}
```

I want to check if at least one property is not null.

How to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: @V4Vendetta That will only check if they don't match.. not if they're not null.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead false when they have the same value or `null` :) don't know what is the exact scenario so commented :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reflection can help you:

```
A myInstance = new A();
Type myType = myInstance.GetType();
if (myType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance)
   .Any(property => propoerty.CanRead && property.GetValue(myInstance, null) != null)) 
{ /* something is not null in myInstance */}
```

Doesn't matter how many properties your class have.

*Note: as comments pointed out, this won't check non-public and set-only properties would blow it up. Code has been tweaked.*

Comment: Feel free to accept, and always remember error-checking ( I left it out to keep code short)

Comment: @loviji Why use reflection? Don't you know what properties your class has? Doesn't the class have just two properties?

Comment: Why waste time writing non-reusable code ? This can be slapped in a method and used on *anything*. Other real-world case: what if a property is added/removed ? This approach allows you to not care what's in there.

Comment: What about performance? For class with two (or even three) props it's better to use plain comparison (x.prop1 != null || x.prop2 != null)

Comment: Your code also tests `static` properties. If at least one static property of the type is non-null, it doesn't even matter what `myInstance` you come with, the result will always be `true`. Also, if the type has just one property of a (non-nullable) value type, like an integer prperty or an enum property, this will always be true, no matter what instance, because that property can never be null. Finally, if the class has a set-only property, the above code will throw an exception at runtime! So as you can see, there can be many problems using reflection.

Comment: And the above technique doesn't test `internal`, `protected` and `private` properties, even if they are accessible in the context.

Comment: Tweaked to include nonpublics and make it set-only safe.

Answer (score 1):

It can be 1 line.. like this:

```
if (instanceOfA.field1 != null || instanceOfA.field2 != null)
```

..in fact, for strings, it might be best to test like this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(instanceOfA.field1) ||
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(instanceOfA.field2))
```

Comment: If the class has more than a handful of properties this approach is a nightmare

Answer (score 1):

```
if(obj.field1 != null || obj.field2 != null)
```